# Home folder name different than user name

Tags: dual-boot, home-directory, username

I just started dual booting Ubuntu and OpenSUSE, and sharing the home partition which I labeled `HOME`.  As this gets more and more exciting, I want to try out the different distros; but still keep Ubuntu as my main distro as I've used it for a few years now.

In any case, when I installed OpenSuse I named the user `diego_suse` in order to have home folder `HOME/diego_suse` be different than `HOME/diego` which I have in Ubuntu.

Ideally, I would like to keep the personal files in `HOME/diego` and the configuration files in each of `HOME/ubuntu` and `HOME/suse`, and hopefully keep my username as `diego` in both systems.

Is this even possible? How can I go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: There is very likely a way. But why do you do that? you will have more problems than the thing is worth.

Comment: I'd like to keep my personal documents in a common (neutral) place, but not have the local configuration files interfere with each other.   A secondary issue is that I dislike using `diego_suse` as a username in order to differentiate the home folder from `HOME/diego` corresponding in Ubuntu.

Comment: ubuntu and opensuse is two different distro, and remember some configuration are stored in `$HOME` directory. Like @A.B. said, this is not worth, it will cause more harm than good.

Comment: This explains it best: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/different-linux-distros-sharing-the-same-home-folder And yes it works and causes no problems. I have the same setup for a 5 OS version where I even have a Unix amongst them.

Comment: Thank you for your positive answer Rinzwind.  The good thing about Linux is that there are no limits on what one can do.  A.B. and Aizuddin, I do understand the risks involved, but if I didn't want to take them I'd be using Windows =)